# Separate cookies on different sites

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, tomcat, cookies

There is a script that connects to the site.

Let's say there is Site1.com and Site2.com (client side pages) on which this script is connected (These sites are completely different, not connected in any way). When loading this script, the server (Tomcat) puts the session id cookie and accordingly gives it the site.com domain (server address) and path = /. After the site is fully loaded, the script makes Ajax request to the server (CORS is configured).

The problem is that: I open the Site1, cookies are put, all the cases. Then I open the Site2 it turns out so that cookies delivered on Site1, but with the domain of the server, will be the same and on Site2.

I tried to separate them using path in cookies, but this led to the fact that this cookie is now not picked up by Ajax.

How else can you separate them?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by Site1 and Site2? Are these the client side pages or are they servers? Please make these terms consistent through your question :)

Comment: @TomAnderson update content.